# docker: Reuse another container's network stack and connect to that container

Tags: docker, networking, vpn

I'm trying to use [bubuntux/nordvpn](https://github.com/bubuntux/nordvpn) to provide a VPN to other containers. I'm trying to get the following setup to work:

1. Use bubuntux/nordvpn to define a `vpn` service
2. Define a container `foo` using `network_mode: service:vpn` to access the internet
3. Define another container `bar` also using `network_mode: service_vpn` to access the internet

So far, this works like a charm - however, now I'd like to make `foo` and `bar` able to connect to each other (e.g. so that `bar` can run `curl http://foo` and it would work), while still using the vpn for connections to the outside. Is this possible to do?

Here's a simple demo `docker-compose` (only need to fill in nordvpn username & password):

```
version: "2"

services:

  vpn:
    image: 'bubuntux/nordvpn'
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    devices:
      - "/dev/net/tun"
    ports:
      - 8080:80   # foo
    environment:
      USER: "XXXXX"
      PASS: "YYYYY"
      COUNTRY: "ch"
      CATEGORY: "P2P"
      OPENVPN_OPTS: "--inactive 3600 --ping 10 --ping-exit 60"
      NETWORK: "192.168.0.0/24"
    restart: "unless-stopped"


  foo:
    image: 'nginx'
    network_mode: service:vpn

  bar:
    image: 'giantswarm/tiny-tools'
    network_mode: service:vpn
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'while sleep 1; do curl -sS http://foo/; done'"
```

The curl-command from `bar` will fail:

```
bar_1  | curl: (6) Could not resolve host: foo
bar_1  | curl: (6) Could not resolve host: foo
...
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: Instead of `foo`, you can just use `localhost`, since your containers share a network namespace.

Comment: Hm that does not seem to work - I was however able obtain the correct ip to use by doing `docker network inspect` on the created network.

Comment: That should absolutely work, and I would encourage you to update your question with the *specific* commands you used to test it out. A key reason to publishing ports like that  is that you *don't* need to use `docker inspect` to find the container ip.